# STR_REPLACE from TXT file to string (with Comma Separator)

Tags: php, arrays, string, str-replace, keyword

I want to filter Keywords from a string (with Comma Separator) according to a list created in a TXT file by using STR_REPLACE.

If the keyword you'll find in the TXT list, then it will delete from the string.

```
$db_tag_new = str_replace('The,',"",$db_tag);
```

---

My string: (Every word have a Comma Separator)

```
$db_tag="The,To,In,A,Of,Is,That,Will,And,Be,For,Rates,Or,Bank,0,It,More,Brexit,With,At,Has,Eu,Have,Said,Would,As,This,Britain,He,May,On,Pound,Are,Interest,Carney,By,They,But,Getty,First,Images,Vote,About,Leave,Even,Inflation,S,Up,Also,Negative";
```

thebadlist.txt: (New line every word)

```
The
To
In
A
Of
Is
That
Will
And
```

---

the result:

```
$db_tag="Rates,Bank,Brexit,Britain,Pound,Interest,Carney";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what have you tried so far

Comment: You just want every word to be in a new line?

Comment: i tried to do a function handy with all the word but  i hope thaere are a automatically way to do that with a loop @RiggsFolly

Comment: @RafaelShkembi no i want a loop of every keyword in the string that cheack if is in the "BADLIST" and if is it he delete the word from the string

Comment: aha ok now i get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `file()` to read your `list.txt` that will read each line into an array. You can then use `str_replace()` as that allows param1 and param2  be arrays, although you will only need to use an array for parameter1

```
<?php

$db_tag="The,To,In,A,Of,Is,That,Will,And,Be,For,Rates,Or,Bank,0,It,More,Brexit,With,At,Has,Eu,Have,Said,Would,As,This,Britain,He,May,On,Pound,Are,Interest,Carney,By,They,But,Getty,First,Images,Vote,About,Leave,Even,Inflation,S,Up,Also,Negative";

$filters = file('list.txt');
// add commas to the occurances
for ($i=0; $i<count($filters); $i++) {
    $filters[$i] = rtrim($filters[$i]) . ',';
}

$db_tag = str_replace($filters, '', $db_tag);

echo $db_tag.PHP_EOL;
```

With a `list.txt` file containing

```
The
To
In
A
Of
Is
That
Will
And
Or
```

RESULT:

> Be,For,Rates,Bank,0,It,More,Brexit,With,At,Has,Eu,Have,Said,Would,As,This,Britain,He,May,On,Pound,Are,Interest,Carney,By,They,But,Getty,First,Images,Vote,About,Leave,Even,Inflation,S,Up,Also,Negative

Comment: Hi @riggsfolly Thanks for the solution, but it does not work. Maybe because what separates in the list (TXT file) is that each row has 1 keywords (and not Comma Separator).

Comment: See amended code with the `rtrim($filters[$i]) ` added in the loop to remove the newlines

Comment: use   file_get_content() instead of file().

Comment: @RiggsFolly You are right...I'm used to keep strings in files, but in this case file() is better.

Comment: This is the new output (when i put rtrim($filters[$i]) to the loop) "The,,,,,,,,nd,Be,For,Rates,Or,Bank,0,It,More,Brexit,With,t,Has,Eu,Have,Said,Would,s,This,Britain," @RiggsFolly

Comment: Then you are missing something, I just added my code and the `list.txt` file I used in my test and the results Looks to me like you missed the `. ','` in `$filters[$i] = rtrim($filters[$i]) . ',';` **Refresh this page**

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have another question if you can help me pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38325484/textbetweentags-php-file-get-content